# How is it possible for a meta material to turn a push into a pull? Wouldn't that violate conservation of momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

This article: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/05/190524140857.htm seemed fine until I hit this quote: "If you were wearing a football helmet made of this material and something hit the helmet, you'd never feel that hit on your head. By the time the energy reaches you, it's no longer pushing. It's pulling,". In other parts it talks about reduced impact forces, perhaps they can reduce impulse, but force is the same?? confused :/

Comment: Hmmmm… perhaps there is energy stored in the meta materials origami geometry bs, that can overcome the initial momentum. No wait, each bit of origami would have initial momentum of zero and the incoming projectile momentum is still out of balance.

Comment: There is a video! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjt2lOjMdJ0&feature=youtu.be it is really helpful to see what the experiment looks like, with out that I was hung up on words like chain, tension, unit cell, wave, heck even impact I guess cause you don't know what is being impacted where...

Answer (score 0):

Looked it up, because I had not heard of this before. This is not an answer but a discussion too long for comments.

I found some analysis, [lots of link](http://www.mss.science/packages/mss-oimm-booklet.pdf)s,but they are not really concerned about momentum conservation.

> How is it possible for a meta material to turn a push into a pull? Wouldn't that violate conservation of momentum?

They use classical wave motion in the meta material and the concept of refraction for changing momentum direction. This in my opinion means that the metamaterial  picks up the conservation of momentum which in the end should become heat, radiation directed so as to balance the momentum overall..

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the original article.  It does not claim to turn a push into a pull.  Instead, it describes a mechanical structure in which rarefaction waves travel faster than compression waves.   An impact at one end of the structure generates *both* compression and rarefaction waves, and the rarefaction wave reaches the far end of the structure before the compression wave does, *if the structure is long enough*.